# How to add an Empty singleton to Dictionary type?

Tags: f#

```
module Extension =  
    type Dictionary<'T,'U> with
        member this.Update (x: Dictionary<_,_>) =
            for kvp in x do
                this.[kvp.Key] <- kvp.Value
            this
        /// This is wrong too, I wanted to use
        /// static let EmptyDictionary = Dictionary<'T,'U>() 
        static member EmptyDictionary = Dictionary<'T,'U>()
        /// Should not modify it, needs to be readonly.
        member this.Empty = Dictionary<'T,'U>.EmptyDictionary
```

In order to mimic the python dictionary `update` function, I need an empty dictionary so as to avoid instantiating a new one each time no update is required. (I could alternatively use `null`, but normally I would avoid it.)

The above has a warning that "a type constraint when 'T: equality is missing".

#### Update

The following demostrate the use case of my code.

Suppose `x` is a dictionary, I can merge it with `y` (update `x`) by `x.Update y`

And if I don't want to update `x` but still need to pass in a `y`, I can use `x.Update x.Empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per F# spec:

**14.11 Additional Constraints on CLI Methods**

> F# treats some CLI methods and types specially, because they are common in F# > programming and cause extremely difficult-to-find bugs. For each use of the > following constructs, the F# compiler imposes additional ad-hoc constraints:
>
> - x.Equals(yobj) requires type ty : equality for the static type of x
> - x.GetHashCode() requires type ty : equality for the static type of x
> - new Dictionary() requires A : equality, for any overload that does not > take an
>     IEqualityComparer

So if you are not intended to mutate empty dictionary, then you can just use a different overload of constructor for `Dictionary<'K, 'V>` and pass default comparer.

Also currently static member `EmptyDictionary` will return a fresh instance of dictionary on every call and I'm not sure that this is intentional. You can use a dedicated type to store a unique singleton instance of empty dictionary for every pair of type arguments

```
open System.Collections.Generic

module Extension =
    type EmptyDictionaryHolder<'T, 'U>() = 
        static let value = new Dictionary<'T, 'U>(EqualityComparer<'T>.Default)
        static member Value: IDictionary<'T, 'U> = value :> _

    type IDictionary<'T,'U> with
        static member EmptyDictionary = EmptyDictionaryHolder<'T, 'U>.Value

        member this.Update (x: IDictionary<_,_>) =
            for kvp in x do
                this.[kvp.Key] <- kvp.Value
            this

        member this.Empty = Dictionary<'T,'U>.EmptyDictionary
```

Comment: You are right. I should have used `static let ...` however that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the problem, but it seems that writing `new Dictionary<'K, 'V>()` introduces an `equality` constraint on `'K`. But since the constraint is not required on the generic type itself, this causes a mismatch.

So, I don't know how to fix the definition using the style that you were using, but I would probably use something a bit different anyway:

```
type Dictionary<'T,'U> with
    member this.Update (x: IDictionary<_,_>) =
        for kvp in x do
            this.[kvp.Key] <- kvp.Value
        this

module Dictionary =
  let Empty<'T, 'U when 'T : equality> = Dictionary<'T,'U>()
```

This uses the fact that you can have a module with the same name as a  type, and so it adds `Update` as an extension but `Dictionary.Empty` is a generic value. This lets you write:

```
Dictionary.Empty.Update(dict [1, "hi"; 2, "bye"])
```